# Unable to mount external encrypted disk

Tags: mount, encryption

Running Kubuntu 17.10 I have an external hard disk of 500GB split into two partitions of equal sizes. One partition is an NTFS partition and the other is an encrypted partition. When I connect the disk to my laptop, Device Notifier shows entries for both partitions separately.

Output of `sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdd1` is:

```
LUKS header information for /dev/sdd1

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha1
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      40 50 .. ..
MK salt:        b4 cb .. ..
MK iterations:  16500
UUID:           3a2bf693-..

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
        Iterations:             66251
        Salt:                   42 ba .. ..
        Key material offset:    8
        AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
```

When I try mounting the partition with `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdd1 lukslvm`, it asks for a password. When I enter a correct password, it produces no error.

After this, `ls -lA /dev/mapper` shows:

```
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Feb 11 09:52 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Feb 11 09:52 cryptswap1 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Feb 11 09:52 kubuntu--vg-root -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Feb 11 09:52 kubuntu--vg-swap_1 -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Feb 13 16:32 lukslvm -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Feb 11 09:52 sda3_crypt -> ../dm-0
```

Output of `sudo lsblk -f` is:

```
NAME            FSTYPE      LABEL            UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                 
├─sda1          vfat                         E551-A70F                              /boot/efi
├─sda2          ext4                         4b..   /boot
└─sda3          crypto_LUKS                  9f..   
  └─sda3_crypt  LVM2_member                  6d.. 
    ├─kubuntu--vg-root
    │           ext4                         29..   /
    └─kubuntu--vg-swap_1
                swap                         6f..   
      └─cryptswap1
                swap                         01..   [SWAP]
sdb                                                                                 
├─sdd1          crypto_LUKS                  3a..   
│ └─lukslvm     ext4        efinso-X53U-back 6a..   
└─sdd2          ntfs        backup           64..                       
sr0
```

Output of `cryptsetup status lukslvm` is:

```
/dev/mapper/lukslvm is active.
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 256 bits
  device:  /dev/sdd1
  offset:  4096 sectors
  size:    586078488 sectors
  mode:    read/write
```

The device notifier still shows the volume as not mounted.

When I try to mount it using the device notifier, it produces an error informing me that it can not be mounted.

In Dolphin, when I try to mount it, it produces an error:

> An error occurred while accessing 'efinso-X53U-back', the system
>   responded: The requested operation has failed:
>
> ```
> Error mounting /dev/dm-4 at /media/sandip/efinso-X53U-back: Command-line mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/dm-4" "/media/sandip/efinso-X53U-back"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: 
>   mount: /media/sandip/efinso-X53U-back: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/lukslvm.
> ```

I am able to mount NTFS partition without difficulty.

Also, external hard disks with only one encrypted partition on them load without any error.

What could have gone wrong? How do I set it right?

FWIW, there is a chance that last time I used the encrypted partition, I forgot to eject it.

Comment: I assume you are using luks. Have you tried mounting through the command line using `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdX2 lukslvm`? Is it happending for other disks as well? - Try creating a temporary encrypted usb drive with only one partition and mount it as well.

Comment: @user8162 Thanks. KDE Partition Manager shows the partition as /dev/sdc1 luks. `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 lukslvm` command produces an error: Device /dev/sdc1 doesn't exist or access denied

Comment: @user8162 I tried another USB Drive with a similar set-up. Same result. I will try creating a USB drive with only encrypted partition on it.

Comment: Here is the error in Dolphin when I try opening it in Dolphin. `An error occurred while accessing '199.0 MiB Encrypted Drive', the system responded: The requested operation has failed: Error unlocking /dev/sdd2: Command-line `cryptsetup luksOpen "/dev/sdd2" "luks-xx"  ' exited with non-zero exit status 5: Device luks-xx already exists.
`

Comment: The error `error: Device /dev/sdc1 doesn't exist or access denied` is probably caused by a typo: You are using `/dev/sdd1` as stated in your question, not `/dev/sdc1`, please try again from the commandline with `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 lukslvm` - please tell us if that works or what kind of error you get. If the devicename changes every time you plugin your drive, you should use the UUID - you can get that by using `cryptsetup luksUUID  </dev/yourdevice>`, which enables you to replace your device path in future commands with `UUID=luks-ID-ID-ID`

Comment: @RobertRiedl Thanks.  `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 lukslvm` asks for a password prompt. If I enter a correct password, it produces an error  `Cannot use device /dev/sdc1 which is in use (already mapped or mounted).`  If I enter an incorrect password, it produces an error `No key available with this passphrase.`

Comment: Is it mounted ? Check with `sudo mount`

Comment: @RobertRiedl Thanks for editing the question. The error crept in because I run the two commands at two different times. The sdx number changes across sessions.

Comment: @RobertRiedl I do not think so. `sudo mount G sdb1` produces no output. BTW, G is short for grep, etc. in Oh My Zsh that I use

Comment: Does your Oh My Zsh substitute for a pipe `| `?

Comment: @RobertRiedl Yes. OK. To simplify things, `sudo mount | grep sdb1` produces no output :)

Comment: I think we got to the correct command with `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 lukslvm` but, well , *something* is keeping your device busy - you need to find out what that is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73000/discussion-between-deshmukh-and-robert-riedl).

Comment: Maybe you are unplugging,and then replugging the external drive.....either that or are you trying to plug in a backup of an encrypted partition after the original has already been mounted?  In either case they will both try to use the same /dev/mapper/ name, which will give you the "already exists" error you are getting.  I'm just bringing this up because you say /dev/sdd1 in one place, and /dev/sdc1 in another.

Comment: @SunnyDaze The question now does not have that error. I have corrected it

Comment: Why does your new info show sdd partitions being under sdb?  sdb and sdd are separate devices.  Maybe if you plug the drive into the USB port it was formatted on?  Also, is sdd1 a backup of sda3?  If so, they will not be able to be mounted at the same time as they will have the same /dev/mapper name "kubuntu--vg-root"

Comment: Even if sdd1 isn't a backup, if it was created with the same "kubuntu--vg-root" name, you won't be able to mount it after sda3 has been mounted.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to user @ukos, in comments the following solution was mentioned and it fixed the issue for me. I'm posting here as possible solution. Pay attention `sudo` in command, without it, it gives error:

```
$ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sde1 lukslvm
Device /dev/sde1 doesn't exist or access denied.
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sde1 lukslvm
Enter passphrase for /dev/sde1:
```

After I entered correct answer, it opened this disk in file manager too.